# Show tab only in Salesforce1, not regular Salesforce site?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

Can I prevent a tab from being visible outside of Salesforce1? For the version of a VF page we want to include in the Salesforce1 app, we trimmed a lot out from the regular desktop version so the mobile version is very basic and limited, but useful for on-the-go.

So, I made an entirely new VF page for the mobile version. I made a new tab for the mobile page, and checked the box to make it available for Salesforce1, then I added it to the mobile navigation.

However, this tab appears in my regular Salesforce org, and can be gotten to while on the regular desktop version of Salesforce.

I don't want users to be able to get to this mobile VF page from the regular Salesforce org site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single tab and leverage the uitheme global variable to determine which page to serve up

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_vf_uitheme.htm

Not sure about preventing the tab from showing up in desktop at all.